# How will google index my multilanguage website?

Tags: php, jquery, html

The website I'm building has two languages (Dutch and English).

You can switch language by selecting a flag (after clicking a form post will be submitted via Jquery). The language is stored in session and with a cookie. the page will refresh and change it's content according to the selected language. (Also HTML lang changes).

Will google correctly index my website? And if for example the user is English, will google display the english version of my website in the results?

Comment: No google will have a hard time. Your url need to be unique for each language. Try to add an abbr of each language in the url. like yourwebsite.com/nl/about-us and yourwebsite.com/about-us

Comment: Using cookies for this is nonsense. You rob people the ability to pass on the URL to a specific piece of content in a specific language; and even their simple expectation to see the same content when they themselves call the same URL again on a different device, or after your cookie has expired, will be disappointed. This information belongs into the URL, period.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an individual URL for each language.
Best way would be to use English as default `/pagename` and use the language prefix for all other languages e.g. `/nl/pagename`, `fr/pagename`.
You could also use a query parameter e.g. `/pagename?language=nl`
You should add meta links to all other languages:

EN
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="/nl/pagename" />`
or
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="/pagename?language=nl" />`

NL
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/pagename" />`

Answer (score 0):

as @marcobiedermann pointed out, there are many ways to denote a page in a different language

you might also consider adding your language to the html tag like

`<html lang="en">`

this is part of the [fronend checklist](https://github.com/thedaviddias/Front-End-Checklist#html-tags)

the documentation for the lang attr can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the problem if the pages will get the duplication tag. I prefer using the toast for the multi-lang website. as it works good as compare to the other tools

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. What is the toast? How is it better?